# How to generate temporary link for the password recovery?

Tags: url, coldfusion, token, temporary, password-recovery

I have built a new single page app with the login process. At first I have used a security question to recover a user's password. Same process I used when the administrator sets up a new account. The system automatically generates a temporary password and sends the link to the user, based on the entered email address.

Then I saw few articles where is highly recommended to avoid sending any kind of passwords through the email. The alternative solution they proposed is to generate a temporary link. For this they use `tokens`. The link will have `url` parameters with the token combination. This token is saved in the database table with an expiration date/flag. After a user clicks on `forgot password`, enters email address and clicks send. Here is [an example of this method with PHP](https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/create-email-based-password-reset-feature-login-script/)

First I have created table with these fields. Example:

```
RecID   int
Email   varchar(80)
Salt    varchar(32)
Token   varchar(50)
Expires datetime
```

One thing that I'm not sure about is `selector` in the PHP example. My guess is this is something similar to `Salt` that I should use in combination with `hash()`. My question is should I use `createUUID()` in combination with a salt and token or not? Here is [an example from Raymond Camden](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2006/07/30/Generating-OneTime-URLs-with-ColdFusion).

I'm curious what would be a better option as well as the approach. If I generate a new account for a user, should I send the link with an expiration of 24 hours? Then a new user can create the password. Or is there is better option for this? Also are there any drawbacks to the solution provided with PHP above? If anyone has any suggestions or better examples please let me know.

Comment: From what I can tell, `selector` doesn't relate to any kind of salt, but a helper for preventing a timing attack. Watch the video on the page you linked for the PHP example. He talks about what he's doing with `selector`. And since you aren't creating a new password, you don't need salt and hash in this case. I wouldn't recommend generating a new account for something as simple as a password reset. That would probably cause more headaches than necessary. And for expirations, I'd drop it to about 20-30 minutes rather than 24 hours. If someone is resetting password, they'll probably be quick.

Comment: Also, you can never go wrong following OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Another big question to answer is do you need this level of security? You have a lot of users performing a lot of actions, does the data you're protecting justify the trade-offs that you'll make for the enhanced security? My argument would be that if it requires a significant level of security, then the login system should possibly be handled by one of your senior developers that you've referenced, followed by a lot of code review (including some devs who are familiar with breaching logins), and review by upper management. Login systems aren't trivial, especially when they need high security.

Comment: @Shawn I have not looked over `selector`. Is there anything similar in ColdFusion? There is no need to `hash` token before it's saved in DB? I would definitely implement this feature for resetting the password. No matter how sensitive is the data in my system I still would try to user some higher level of security measure. I'm the only developer working on this project and my resources are limited. I'm trying to get rid of security question process for resetting the password. Also I would mention this. Users can't create account by them self. Only administrators can setup new account.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to hash the token as it's already a randomly generated string. Hashing it further protects your users if a bad guy has access to your database, but then you've also got other issues. It's not a bad thing, but not 100% necessary. The purpose of the token is to provide something that you send to the user and they send back to you to provide initial verification of their identity and allow you to match their account so that they can reset their password. For more fun reading, check out Troy Hunt's post. https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know

Comment: For what `selector` is used for, check out the video in the link you posted. He talks about how he's using it. It's not really a "thing" that would be in ColdFusion, or really even in PHP. It's just a concept of how he's mitigating a problem (timing attacks).

Comment: "I'm the only developer working on this project and my resources are limited." -- That was the primary reason that I suggested you evaluate the level of complexity needed for your login and data protection. Strong cyber security is not something that can be easily done. And it's easy for the effort to outweigh the risks. That's why there needs to be some analysis of what an acceptable risk level is. And if a high level of security is necessary, it's probably not something that should be left to a single developer.

Comment: @Shawn I have briefly explained that we do not store social securities, credit cards, etc... At the same time there are addresses, phone numbers, data related to each user that should not be exposed. After reviewing the options I decided that recovery of the password with temporary link is good approach.

Comment: I apologize if I've come across as preachy. Most of my career has been spent in areas where information security is a very big deal (or became a big deal after the bad things that we said could happen finally did), so I take it pretty seriously (if you didn't notice). Both over- and under-engineering security controls can make your days a LOT longer. You have to find the balance between driving your users away and keeping them appropriately safe. Security is hard, and it's _very_ easy to leave an exploitable hole. The lessons you learn are never lessons you want to have to learn the hard way.

Comment: Back to your original question, no `selector` has nothing to do with salting or hashing. It is purely used to mitigate a timing attack (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41691/timing-attack-and-good-coding-practices). It separates the lookup of the token from the validation of the token. Definitely watch the video in your link. He does a good job of explaining what his code does.

Comment: In ColdFusion, you can use `createUUID()` to make your token. Tthe algorithm underlying that function is cryptographically secure, which is what you're going for. It would be very difficult (and very nearly impossible) to duplicate.

Comment: @Shawn I mentioned in previous answers there is no such a function/method in ColdFusion that can replicate `selector`. I was able to use createUUID() to generate the token. Then I use `dateAdd()` to set expiration time for the token (I use 30min now() + 30 min). The nest step is saving that in reset table with `email`. The very last I sent email with the link: `http://exmaiple.org?token=......`. Use will click on the link, I will check if token exists and if it's valid. Then I run query to pull the token and check if it's valid/not expired. Then user can enter new password.

Comment: I think we may be talking around each other. In the PHP tutorial `selector` isn't related to a function or method, it's just a constant-length variable added in the database to mitigate a timing attack against your pw reset functionality. I believe there are ways to do constant-time "string comparisons" in CF, especially if you drop back into Java, but this may be  more extreme than your application calls for (at least as you've described). And that also would relate to a timing attack on your actual login. I think your best bet to deal with this threat would be simple logging and limiting.